How to replace microjack on stereo earplugs with microphone
I broke a microjack connector. It is attached to a set of stereo earplugs with built in microphone. I know how to solder, but I am not sure how to find the correct replacement plug and how to identify and connect the wires correctly. Apologies if this is the wrong forum.


These are nearly impossible to solder and repair and matching the resistance after they have been soldered once.

Like with any similar question, you need to figure out how the wires were connected to original plug.
Either by visually checking how they were connected, or with a multimeter.
The tip and ring are left and right anyway, so no need to worry about that.
You need to check which way the ground and mic are, as there are two different standards, OMAP and CTIA, or in other words, Apple and Android.
